# Shortest-code for prime-calculation

Tags: java, primes, code-golf

The newspaper for the Computer Science-line at my school (called [readme](http://img.abakus.no/readme-pdf/readme0903_tilweb.pdf), it's norwegian, page 19) had a fun competition to write the shortest possible Java-code for the following problem.

> Take in an integer (as a string in the first entry of a string array, since the Java main method only takes a string array) as an argument, and write out first all numbers below this number that are primes, and then all numbers that are not primes. The shortest code wins!

As an answer, I will post the shortest Java-code that won the competition. I wonder if the Stack Overflow Community can make a code that is shorter If you know Norwegian, you will see that you could've won a bottle of champagne if you had done it, but unfortunately the last submit date of the competition is over.

How would you have solved this problem?

Comment: In what language? Java isn't exactly known for its brevity.

Comment: I agree.. Edited it and made it a Community Wiki. :)

Comment: Does it have to have a main?  Your question said it takes an integer, but main takes only string arguments?

Comment: Added some clarification.. :)

Comment: Shortest source code or byte code?

Comment: I removed the Java-requirement

Comment: You may want to tag this as `language-agnostic` and `rosetta-stone`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was already doing it in Haskell before you changed the title to "Java". Since this is a community wiki, here it is anyway.

```
primes n = 
let sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x | x<-xs, x `mod` p /= 0] in 
let primes = takeWhile (<n) $ sieve [2..] in 
([0..n] \\ primes, primes)

*Main> primes 20
([0,1,4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20],[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19])
```

**(edit:)** Shortening names and removing whitespace makes it 79 chars:

```
p n=let s(p:xs)=p:s[x|x<-xs,x`mod`p/=0];r=takeWhile(<n)$s[2..]in(r,[0..n-1]\\r)
```

here also the resulting pair's order is swapped, and `n-1` is used, as per the spec.

Using sub-optimal trial division brings it down to **50 chars**:

```
p n=partition(\k->all((>0).rem k)[2..k-1])[2..n-1]
```

Comment: Nice. This could be shortened by using simple trial division, rather than a sieve of sorts (and the above algorithm has worse performance than trial division; see the Melissa O'Neill's paper about this).

Comment: @ Gracenotes do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: Accepted this answer, if somebody comes up with something shorter I will change the acceptance =)

Comment: I think Gracenotes is referring to this paper: [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes][1]

  [1]: http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The Java-code that won the competition (153 bytes without spacing, spacing included here for readability):

```
class F {
   public static void main(String[] a) {
      for (int i, j, k = 2; k-- > 0;)
         for (i = 1; i++ < new Long(a[0]);) {
            for (j = i; i % --j > 0;)
               ;
            if (k > 0 ? j < 2 : j > 1)
               System.out.println(i);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: This program does not terminate for inputs larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: new Long(String) is rather expensive cf. Long.parseLong(String) for a loop, but it is shorter. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's a Java version of [the previous Haskell answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838004/shortest-java-code-for-prime-calculation/838072#838072) This program terminates for all arguments, given sufficient heap.

```
import fj.data.Natural;
import fj.data.Stream;
import static fj.data.Stream.*;
import static fj.pre.Ord.naturalOrd;
import fj.pre.Show;
import static fj.pre.Show.streamShow;
import static fj.pre.Show.naturalShow;
import static fj.data.Natural.ZERO;
import static fj.data.Natural.natural;
import fj.P1;
import fj.F;
import static fj.data.Enumerator.naturalEnumerator;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Primes2
  {public static Stream<Natural> sieve(final Stream<Natural> xs)
    {return cons(xs.head(), new P1<Stream<Natural>>()
      {public Stream<Natural> _1()
        {return sieve(xs.tail()._1().filter(new F<Natural, Boolean>()
          {public Boolean f(final Natural x)
            {return !naturalOrd.eq(x.mod(xs.head()), ZERO);}}));}});}

  public static Stream<Natural> primes(final Natural n)
    {return sieve(forever(naturalEnumerator, natural(2).some()))
            .takeWhile(naturalOrd.isLessThan(n));}

  public static void main(final String[] a)
    {final Natural n = natural(new BigInteger(a[0])).some();
     final Show<Stream<Natural>> s = streamShow(naturalShow);
     s.println(primes(n));
     s.println(range(naturalEnumerator, ZERO, n)
               .minus(naturalOrd.equal(), primes(n)));}
}
```

[The fj package is from here.](http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava)

Answer (score 1):

My attempt in Ruby. 93 characters.

```
def s n
(a=(2..n).to_a).each{|n|a.reject!{|k|k%n==0&&k/n!=1}}
p[[1]+a,(2..n).to_a-a]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

if you would like a js code : n is the max (62 chars)

```
  for(i=1; i<n;i++)
    {
        for(f = j= 2;j<i && f;)
            f = i%j++
        if(f) console.log(i)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 65 characters

```
print[i for i in range(2,input())if all(i%j for j in range(2,i))]
```

Usage:

```
>>> print[i for i in range(2,input())if all(i%j for j in range(2,i))]
70
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand and smart code may be like:

```
public class test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = i / 2; j >= 2; j--) {
                if (i % j == 0)
                    count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 0)
                System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, two more Haskell definitions. The archetypal

```hs
primes = map head . scanl (\\) [2..] . map (\p -> [p, p+p..]) $ primes
         where
         (\\) = Data.List.Ordered.minus
```

and the absolute champion in brevity,

```hs
nubBy (((>1).).gcd) [2..]           -- (((>1).).gcd) meaning (\a b -> gcd a b > 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

133 characters :-)

```
class F {

    public static void main(String[] z) {

        l:
        for (int a=1,b; a < z; a += 2) {

            for (b = 2; b < a; b++)
                if (a % b == 0) 
                    continue l;
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lists 1 as a prime, does not list 2 as a prime, does not list non-primes, and does not run without modifications when tested w/jre-1.7